# Does the tile on dashboard need to be manually refeshed in DirectQuery mode?

Tags: powerbi

I have made report in Power BI using the direct query approach. The data source is an onpremise SQL server.

Couple of tiles from the report are pinned to the dashboard.

When the report is loaded or the dashboard is loaded then I understand that the underlying data source is queried.

However I am reading that tiles on dashboard can be configured for scheduled refresh (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-data#datasets-in-directqueryliveconnect-mode).

Why does the tile on dashboard need to be manually refeshed in DirectQuery mode?